# Calculate the time difference if values are not equal

Tags: pandas

I am able to calculate the difference (in hours) using:

```
pdf["hours_used"] = (
    pdf["_source_eventTime_right"] - pdf["_source_eventTime_left"]
).astype("timedelta64[h]")
```

This is working as expected. But I want to return NULL for the rows where left and right times are exactly the same. How do I add "if" clause in the hours calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) worked as expected...

```
pdf["hours_used"] = np.where(
    (pdf["_source_eventTime_right"] - pdf["_source_eventTime_left"])
    .astype("int")
    .gt(0),
    (pdf["_source_eventTime_right"] - pdf["_source_eventTime_left"]).astype(
        "timedelta64[h]"
    ),
    np.nan,
)
```